# How to get master view page html hidden field value in inside of Partial View it will lost value when file upload button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, hidden-field

I need to master view page html hidden field value in inside of the PartialView view  i cant get that html hidden control id  " hidImgnam " value in partial view

i think it will lost hidden field value when  is inside of file upload button click is there any other solution for solve this issue

my code below could you please help me as soon as possible

Master View

```
          <input id="ORE_FELICI" type="image"  src="~/Images/UploadButtons/ore.jpg" onclick="PopOpen()" class="imgpht"/>                   
                         <input id="hidImgnam"  type="hidden" />

    <script>
    $("input").click(function () 
{ var id = this.id; $('#hidImgnam').val(this.id); });
</script>
```

Partial View

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        var Folderid =   $('#hidImgnam').val();

        alert(Folderid);
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'post',
            url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
            autoUpload: true,
            formData: { name: document.getElementById('hidImgnam').value },

            done: function (e, data) {
                if (data.result.name == '') {
                    $('.file_name').html('Please Upload valid image...');
                    $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', 0 + '%');

                }
                else {
                    $('.file_name').html("Uploaded Successfully..[ " + data.result.name + " ]");
                }

            }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is the value the alert box is showing? Have you set the value of hidden field somewhere else? You can probably set value attribute of the hidden field & check if the alert box is showing it.

Comment: Your code is okay. Just make sure that the value is set. Try <input id="hidImgnam"  type="hidden" value="blabla" />

Comment: yes i have dynamically set the value in hidden field  $("input").click(function () {
      
        var id = this.id;         
      
       $('#hidImgnam').val(this.id);
    });

Comment: i have updated my full code of the question please check it

Comment: Please help i have same issue ..please help me..